# Replacing escape characters around table-names, column-names in an SQL query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

For example

```
query = " select "2017-06-08" as new_colum, "true" as my_flag, "column1", "column2" from "table1" "
```

The above query should be changed as:

`select "2017-06-08" as new_column, "true" as my_flag, [column1], [column2] from [table1]`. (MS SQL format)

Can I use some parser like jsql parser? Or Is there any other better way?

Comment: how much your query is complex ?

Comment: if we can understand also why you want this changes maybe we can find a better way, so why you want to change this in your query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were not for that your dates are surrounded by double quotes, we could have just done a blanket replacement of `"(.*?)"` with `[$1]` using `String#replaceAll()`.  But the presence of double quoted dates makes the problem more difficult.  My updated answer uses the following pattern to target only non dates in double quotes:

```
(\s+)"([^\d].*?)"
```

This will only match a quoted term preceded by at least one whitespace character, and whose first character inside the quotes is *not* a digit.  This should rule out all dates, and it should not rule out any column since SQL Server column names cannot begin with a number.

I make the assumption here that every quoted column is preceded by whitespace.  This should be OK, assuming the first word in your query string is always a keyword like `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.

```
String query = "select \"2017-06-08\" as new_colum, \"column1\", \"column2\" from \"table1\"";
query = query.replaceAll("(\\s+)\"([^\\d].*?)\"", "$1[$2]");
System.out.println(query);
```

**Output:**

```
select "2017-06-08" as new_colum, [column1], [column2] from [table1]
```

By the way, if you're wondering what the significance is of checking for whitespace before the beginning of a quoted term, try taking out that requirement from the regex.  You will see that `replaceAll()` will than falsely pick up on a *closing* quote as being the start of a term, which it is not.

## Demo

Comment: this is a good solution but it can make problem in case like this `String description = "\"description\"";
String query = "select \"column1\" from \"table1\" where description = " + description;` it will show you `select [column1] from [table1] where description = [description]` instead of `select [column1] from [table1] where description = "description"` so maybe it this solution need more work no?

Comment: @YCF_L I answered using the sample in the OP.  Of course, if quotes have another meaning in the query, e.g. as a string literal, we have a problem.  Ideally though, string literals would be using _single_ quotes.

Comment: ok hope this can help the OP i liked your answer so you have my UV :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Thanks for the answer. But my requirement is just to modify col_names, table_names. Not any other strings.

Comment: What else in your query has double quotes besides database, table, and column names?  Ideally your string literals should use _single_ quotes.  If not, then I think you would need a parser, or a complex series of regexes, to achieve what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Strings like date also has double quotes. So parsers like jsql can do this job?

Comment: @loknath I don't understand your question.

Comment: Other than database, table, and column names even dates(you may see my query) also has double quotes. I need to change quotes around only  table, and column names.

Comment: Then you may need to write some complex logic to parse the query.  I don't think there is a silver bullet solution.

Comment: @loknath Dates *can* be formed from strings using single quotes in SQL Server (e.g. see http://rextester.com/RKMQID1983) so I think Tim's answer is the best solution here - or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @SteveChambers: I cant modify query. My query has dates in double-quotes.

Comment: @loknath I updated my answer again.  This time, it doesn't replace dates which appear in double quotes.  There are a few caviats which I will add to my answer now.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I am very glad that you are taking efforts and improved your answer. It solves the DATE case. But what if query has some other strings like "true" as in my query in the question.(I have edited now for better understanding). Sorry if I was not clear in my initial version of question.

Comment: As I already mentioned, in the general case, you should really be using a parser here.  I won't make an update, because doubtless after covering the `true` case, you would have other edge cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) comes with a dedicated API for parsing T-SQL source code: [
TransactSql ScriptDom available within [`Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx) namespace.

Among different classes, there is a `TSqlParser` class with subclasses for every SQL Server version. For example, for SQL Server 2008 there is following class [`TSql100Parser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsql100parser.aspx).

Regarding this question, [here](https://gist.github.com/philippwiddra/2ee47ac4f8a0248c3a0e) I have found an C# example about parsing a `SELECT` statement.